# Equivalent propositions

Tags: logic, soft-question

Often in Mathematics we find some property to be equivalent to another one, for example, the Principle of Mathematical Induction is equivalent to the Well-Ordering Principle, the action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is equivalent to a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_X$, in Euclidean Geometry we find dozens of axioms equivalent to the fifth postulate, I could go on forever...

I think I understand what it means, for example, in the group action $\Leftrightarrow$ homomorphism example it means that every group action induces a homomorphism $G \to S_X$ and every homomorphism $G \to S_X$ induces a group action $G\times X \to X$. Some authors say that although we use different languages, group actions and homomorphisms (in this context) are equivalent notions.

But, what does that mean precisely?

Does it mean that every theorem concerning group G acting on $X$ be translated to a theorem concerning homomorphisms $G \to X_S$ ?

Comment: I strongly doubt the first claim.